# What is the best way to position these elements with CSS for the best responsive layout?

Tags: html, css, image, svg, layout

I'm creating a website and there is a section where I would like this design to be put in place:

[image]

At the moment, the speech bubbles are svg images set as background images to their own individual divs, the elements inside the speech bubbles are nested within the speech bubble parent div. The problems arise when changing browser widths - the text doesn't stay within the bubbles.

What is the best way to go about turning this design into responsive code with html and CSS only?

This is the html code so far:

```
<!-- Reviews -->
  <section id="reviews">
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
    <section class="visitor-review-1">
      <div class="review-1">
        <img id="user-image-1" src="media/profile-picture-1.png">
        <div id=visitor-comment-1>
          <p>Make sure you visit Santorini when you go to Greece. Its magical! An island that is a volcano, what could be dreamier? Make sure you try the local naturally sweet red wine, sweet tomatoes and lava.
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong><br>Amy Santiago</strong><br>Birmingham, UK
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="visitor-review-2">
      <div class="review-2">
        <img id="user-image-2" src="media/profile-picture-2.png">
        <div id=visitor-comment-2>
          <p>We went to a restaurant with a beautiful terrace called Elinikon and had the most amazing view. Not only the sunset but before and after the sky remains beautiful colours! 100% must see when in Santorini.
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong><br>Dave William</strong><br>London, UK
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
```

and CSS:

```
#reviews {
  padding: 5rem 8rem 5rem 8rem;
  height: 100px;
}

.visitor-review-1 {
  background-image: url(media/speech-bubble-left_1.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30rem;
  height: 350px;
  margin-top: 2.9rem;
}

.visitor-review-2 {
  background-image: url(media/speech-bubble-right.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 30rem;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  top: -9rem;
}

.review-1 {
    width: 40%;
    position: absolute;
}

.review-2 {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 52%;
    position: absolute;
}

#user-image-1 {
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 26px;
}

#visitor-comment-1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 2rem 4rem 0rem 3rem;
    color: rgba(16, 37, 89, 0.78);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#user-image-2 {
    width: 110px;
    position: relative;
    left: 180px;
    top: 26px;
}

#visitor-comment-2 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    padding: 2rem 4rem 0rem 3rem;
    color: rgba(16, 37, 89, 0.78);
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `word-wrap: break-word` in your text classes wrapped inside the speech bubble divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@media` tag to tell your code what to do if the max-width of the screen is some size, example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
   .review-1 {
      width: 550%;
      position: absolute;
}
/*And keep filling in what you want changed at screensizes here*/
}
```